# Active admin - Use controller method in Collection actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

i want to use a custom controller action in one of the member actions of the page .  Iam getting undefined method error .

```
    ActiveAdmin.register_page Post do
      controller do
        def get_last_post
        end
      end

    collection_action :get_details, method: :get do 
      data = get_last_post
    end

    end
```

data = get_last_post throws error .
PS: Post is not a model . Just a page .

Comment: I'd put the `get_last_post` method into the `Post` class.

Comment: The above was just an example class.  Mine is actually a register_page file , and is not linked with any model .  Have edited the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add method in Helper. You can access the method from controller and all the collection actions.

Add method in helper file and try to call it from collection_action

```
module PostHelper
  def get_last_post
  end
end

ActiveAdmin.register_page Post do
  collection_action :get_details, method: :get do 
    data = get_last_post
  end
end
```